# How to read download urls from firebase storage without using a lot of bandwidth?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a react application that only reads from Firebase storage and isn't writing, I built it thinking the images will be uploaded directly to the Firebase interface.

The problem is that the way I am reading the information is costing a lot of bandwidth, I guess what I am doing is bringing all of images to the client although I only need their downloadURL (the link to showcase on the site).

```
try {
   if (albumIndex && albums[+albumIndex]?.images.length <= 1) {
      const albumName = albums[+albumIndex].name;
      const albumsRes = await list(ref(storage, `/albums/${albumName}`), { maxResults: config.maxImagesInAlbum });
      const images = [];
      for (const img of albumsRes.items)
         images.push(await getDownloadURL(img));
      dispatch(addImagesToAlbum(+albumIndex, images));
   }
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
}
```

I thought about possibly having the Download URLs in a database and reading them, but I would like to find a way for Firebase to write them automatically in the database when I upload images/folders to the storage via the console.

It's my first time working with Firebase so I would love it if you could tell me if what I want to do is possible and how to do it, or possibly offer different solutions.

Comment: "I thought about possibly having the Download URLs in a database and reading them, but I would like to find a way for Firebase to write them automatically in the database when I upload images/folders to the storage via the console".  You could use a Cloud Function which is triggered when a file is uploaded to Cloud Storage, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events?gen=2nd

Comment: I did something similar to that but apparently just showing the images on the site takes a lot of bandwidth, even if I get the links from a database. Does any of you know an alternative place where I can store the images or possibly another way to minimize the bandwidth use ?